# Pytorch custom/modified GAN loss equivalent

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to implement a Pytorch version of [Creative Adversarial Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.07068.pdf), a GAN with a modified/custom loss function.

Here are the [formulae for the loss function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqAeM.jpg). I'm using Pytorch's `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` for the discriminator's modified loss function, and it seems to be working, as its loss decreases over epochs, but I don't think `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` is suitable for the generator, as `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` seems to expect `Long` and not `Float` tensors, and the paper’s loss function, particularly the generator's loss, seems to me like it would require floats.

This is my current (initial) thinking for the generator's custom loss:

`y_dim` is the number of classes

`disc_class_layer` = FC layer that outputs a style/class given an input image

The `for` loop attempts to be the equivalent to:

(sigma k=1 up to k) ((1/K)log(Dc(ck|G(z)) + (1 − (1/K)log(1 − Dc(ck|G(z)).

```
class CanGLoss(nn.Module):
def __init__(self,y_dim,labels,disc_class_layer):
    super(CanGLoss,self).__init__()

def forward(self,inp):
    style_loss = 0
    for i in range(1,y_dim+1):
        style_loss += (1/i)*torch.log(disc_class_layer(inp)) + (1 - (1/i))*torch.log(1-disc_class_layer(inp))
    return style_loss*-1
```

Is this on the right track? I am new to custom loss functions and Pytorch and not sure this is the way to go.

Any help would be great!